# Opencv Color spaces and channels

Tags: android, image, opencv

I am developing an image processing App using Android. I have confusion with color spaces and channels. My question is: Opencv is BGR color based, so when I use Android to take picture it will be in RGB format and I want to convert RGB to Lab so what is the order of channels in the Lab color space after conversion. Is it 
L:0
A:1
B:2
or
L:2
A:1
B:0

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former; they are always listed in channel order. `BGR` is `B:0, G:1, R:2`, `Lab` is `L:0, a:1, b:2`, `HSV` is `H:0, S:1, V:2`, etc.

You can check out the [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_lab) on `RGB` to `Lab` conversion, which show the actual formulas used to do the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. however, I followed some tutorial which used to get only image in A-B channels without L as follow: Imgproc.cvtColor(srcOrig, srcOrig, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);   Imgproc.cvtColor(src, imgLab, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2Lab, 3);
List<Mat> lab_planes = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
Core.split(imgLab, lab_planes);Mat channel = lab_planes.get(2);
   channel = Mat.zeros(imgLab.rows(), imgLab.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
// use only AB channels in Lab color space
lab_planes.set(2, channel);
Core.merge(lab_planes,imgLab); so I used 2, is this correct or i need to change it to 0.